# Where I can find the resources for osmdroid 3.0.5

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

Recently, I studied and used the architecture of osmdroid project.

In the beginning, I downloaded the osmdroid-android-3.0.5.jar and inserted it into my android program. It ran smoothly and quickly, especially in loading local map tiles. But I cannot find the code resources for version '3.0.5'.

I found the code resources for version '3.0.8', so I moved it into my project.  And then something terrible happened: Loading local map tiles is very slow !!! When I change the zoom-level of mapview, some map tiles which belong to the last zoom-level just remain !!! The feeling about operation of this software becomes poor !!!

So, how to can I solve this problem ?　And where can I find the code resources for version osmdroid-3.0.5 ?

Thank you very much for the response !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

osmdroid source code is available on Google Code, and there's a branch for 3.0.5.

http://osmdroid.googlecode.com/svn/branches/release_3_0_5/